# Forms and submit in Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

My web app handles info on semesters. The info on this semesters can be displayed on a table, exported as pdf and exported as csv.

My idea is to have one dropdown (semantic ui) from which the users selects the semester (which updates the table on click), and then clicks one of those two export buttons.

I'm struggling with the code and whats the best way to do this.

This is what I have now:

My dropdown (semantic ui)

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
<input id="semester" name="semester" type="hidden">
    <div class="default text">All semesters</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="">Semester</div>
            @foreach($semesters as $semester)
                <div class="item" data-value="<?php echo $semester->id ?> ">
                <a href="{{ url('match/semester/' . $semester->name) }}">{{ $semester->name }}</a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
   </div>
```

For each of the two buttons I created an extra form with a hidden field which is updated to the selected semester using javascript.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'match/pdf')) !!}
    {{ Form::hidden('semester_pdf', $semester) }}
    {!! Form::submit('PDF', ['class' => 'btn btn-success tn-sm']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'match/csv')) !!}
    {{ Form::hidden('semester_csv', $semester) }}
    {!! Form::submit('CSV', ['class' => 'btn btn-success tn-sm']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and the javascript which udpates the value of the hidden fields:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("semester_pdf").value = "WS2016";
    }
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this the right way.

Any help?

Comment: This does not sound too bad to me. If you want to get rid of the JS-"hack" you could add a hidden field to the forms which indicates the desired export format. Both forms point to the same route/method and within the method you choose the selected export service/class/routine/whatever.

Comment: Thats a good idea!
How can I indicate the export format with a hidden field? I'm a bit confused there...

Comment: sorry, my comment was incorrect - you can't get of the js part, you can get rid of the two forms when you set both semester value and export format via Javascript.